# In-app updates check whether it is AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE or AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-core

Is there any option available in the playstore console to configure this value?

Here is the official doc. code:

```
// Creates instance of the manager.
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
          // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
          && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
              // Request the update.
    }
});
```

How do we know about:

```
appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
```

Where to configure the above type? There is no relevant description available on the official doc.

In the AppUpdateInfo.class:

```
public final boolean isUpdateTypeAllowed(int var1) {
        if (var1 == 0) {
            return this.f != null;
        } else if (var1 == 1) {
            return this.e != null;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Where `f` and `e` are the `PendingIntent` and method returns `true` or `false` based on their value.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a way to remotely configure this via Play console. We had to use a network API in our server to check this.

Answer (score 10):

> What is the use of appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)?

This is a very common question.

Many (myself included) interpreted this as a value that could be set somewhere dynamically, e.g. in the Google Play Console.

However that appears to not be the case.  This is a local check that determines whether conditions on the device have been met to show the dialog.

If you want to dynamically configure whether to show Immediate or Flexible updates, you will need to provide it yourself, e.g. from your backend.

For more info: https://medium.com/@jplipata/undocumented-android-in-app-updates-a95efb9b7bd8?source=friends_link&sk=e8085150daa555ea80d07e8419b5341e

Comment: They are going to release it soon, check this out: `Soon you'll be able to specify an in-app update priority for your app release, which will be made available through the in-app update API.
Please see this Android Developer Summit talk for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o_q6hatcIs` (from here: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133299031)

Comment: "whether conditions on the device have been met to show the dialog" - yes! What I found is that if you check this while all that is open is a notification, then even if updateAvailability is UPDATE_AVAILABLE, isUpdateTypeAllowed() will return false (and in the debugger you can see that the intents returned are null). You need to see that an update is Available, open an activity, and then from there call the API again and then isUpdateTypeAllowed() will return true and you'll be able to update.

Answer (score 0):

**The update type (IMMEDIATE or FLEXIBLE) are set inside the app, not the play console.**

Only an app update availibility check is necessary in the first place:

```
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
```

If this check succeeds, you need to start the update flow by yourself

```
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
```

or

```
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
```

regarding this type, the update will be installed in the background or in a blocking view by an play store overlay.

When an flexible app update is triggered and the user leaves the app, you need to check on the next launch if an flexible update is running in the background or finished.

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

Comment: What is the use of appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)?

Comment: It is to ensure, that the desired update type is supported.

Comment: Supported how??

Answer (score 0):

```
appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)

appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
```

I have tried for multiple times to lower down the `versionCode` as compared to the Live App on Play Store.

Maybe in the next update, Google will explain about the `isUpdateTypeAllowed` because right now it's an only ambiguous call.

It is up to the developer to choose which type of update is invoked.

The mode is determined by the app in code.

Please see for further reference https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#start_update